# Dates causing line spread in moderncv

Tags: moderncv

I have prepared a draft of my cv but the dates written on the left side appears in two lines e.g. `06/15 - 09/15` as shown in the image below. Due to this, there is an unusual line space in the description part.

Furthermore, how can I describe about a job experience using bullets or numbering in the description part.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme[blue]{casual}                 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                  
\usepackage[scale=0.8]{geometry}
\recomputelengths                             
\firstname{gjfjg}
\familyname{ffkgkj}
\address{kkj}{dhfjhj}    
\mobile{+845894}                    
\email{cxc@yahoo.com}                     
\photo[96pt]{mintImage3.jpg}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{\textsc{Personal Details}}
\cventry{Date of Birth}{dfdf}{}{}{}{} %arguments 3 to 6 are optional
\cventry{Nationality}{dfdf}{}{}{}{} %arguments 3 to 6 are optional
\cventry{Marital Status}{dfdf}{}{}{}{} %arguments 3 to 6 are optional


\section{\textsc{Experience}}
\subsection{Jobs}
\cventry{06/15 - 09/15}{Internship}{XYZ}{djhfjdhjfhjd}{}{}
\cvline{}{dhjksfhjhsjkfhjksdhfjhdfjdhfjkhjkfhsjkfhsjkfhsjhfjshfjhsjfhskhjshfhsfhjdkshfhfkhdsjkfhsjkfhjkshfjkshhskhfjshjfhskfhjksdhfhsdfhsfhjhjhjkfhjshfjhs}
%%%%
\cventry{08/14 - 02/15}{Market XYZ Analyst}{XYZ}{XYZ}{}{}
\cvline{}{hdhfdsfhjsjhfgsjgfhjsghfgsahjdgsdgahsjdgahjdgjghjadghdghjaghjagdhjagdhjasgdhjagdhjaghhjfggagajghajfghagfhagfhgahfgahjgfjagfhbcbx}
%%%%
\cventry{01/14 - 03/14}{XYZ}{XYZ}{XYZ}{}{}
\cvline{}{hjdbhfhjhsdjkfhjkshfjkhsjkfhsjkfhjkshjkashdjkahdjahdjahdjadhladhlakdjadjlaklajdlajdkajkdjakljakldjlajdklajdjakldjkldjakldj}



\section{\textsc{Computer skills}}
%\cvitem{\textbf{Programming Languages}}{}
\cvitem{}{\textbf{Programming Languages}}
\cvitem{Procedural}{C, C++, python}


\closesection{}                   
\renewcommand{\listitemsymbol}{-} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: presumably you have not made the first column wide enough, but how can you expect anyone to debug your code just from half an image of the output? Please post a full example document as a code block `{}` that demonstrates the problem. You do not have to reveal any secrets, every date can be 00/00/00 and every word can be abcdef so long as it demonstrates the issue.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I will post in a few min

Comment: I have provided a working example. Please have a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace

```
\cventry{06/15 - 09/15}{Internship}{XYZ}{djhfjdhjfhjd}{}{}
\cvline{}{dhjksfhjhsjkfhjksdhfjhdfjdhfjkhjkfhsjkfhsjkfhsjhfjs
hjshfhsfhjdkshfhfkhdsjkfhsjkfhjkshfjkshhskhfjshjfhskfhj
ksdhfhsdfhsfhjhjhjkfhjshfjhs}
```

by

```
\cventry{06/15-09/15}{% no spaces 06/15 - 09/15
Internship}{XYZ}{djhfjdhjfhjd}{}{%
\begin{itemize}
\item hhhhhhh
\item fffffff
\end{itemize}}
```

or

```
\cventry{06/15-09/15}{Internship}{XYZ}{djhfjdhjfhjd}{}{}
\cvline{}{\begin{itemize}
\item hhhhhhh
\item fffffff
\end{itemize}}
```

**Edit: updated** cventry typested using `tabular` with `p{space}` columns. the space reserved for date's column is defined by `\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{0.175\textwidth}` one can redefine it to be larger, example `\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{0.2\textwidth}`

Comment: Could you please tell me the reason, why my dates were not coming in the same line. Your answer is able to solve my problem but I don't know what was wrong with my code

Comment: @skm  answer updated