# How to make dates less awkward looking in moderncv classic theme?

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, moderncv

Here's a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[10pt,legalpaper,sans]{moderncv}        % possible options include font size ('10pt', '11pt' and '12pt'), paper size ('a4paper', 'letterpaper', 'a5paper', 'legalpaper', 'executivepaper' and 'landscape') and font family ('sans' and 'roman')

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}         % to set the default font; use '\sfdefault' for the default sans serif font, '\rmdefault' for the default roman one, or any tex font name

% modern themes
\moderncvstyle{classic}                            % style options are 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'oldstyle' and 'banking'
\moderncvcolor{black}                                % color options 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'green', 'red', 'purple', 'grey' and 'black'

% character encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                   

% adjust the page margins
\usepackage[margin=0.63in]{geometry}
\setlength{\footskip}{10pt}
\usepackage{import}
\nopagenumbers{}

% personal data
\name{FirstName}{LastName}
\phone[mobile]{+1 (111) 111-1111}                   
\email{firstname@gmail.com}    
\social{https://www.linkedin.com/in/firstname/}
\homepage{firstname.github.io}         

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%            content
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Experience}

\vskip 5pt

\begin{itemize}
    
    \item[]{\cventry{November 2022 -- Current}{Research Assistant}{Research Group}{City, ST}{}{
            \vspace{3pt}
            $\bullet$ Placeholder \\
            $\bullet$ Placeholder \\
            $\bullet$ Placeholder \\
            $\bullet$ Placeholder
    }}
    
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

This is how it currently looks:

[image]

The dates in this example get clumped up in the left column. I do not want to increase the size of that column horizontally as that would cause it to take too much space. Is there a way to make the dates look visually aesthetic (similar to the banking theme layout) while keeping the rest of the classic theme?

For example, I would like if they were all on the same line. Something like this:

[image]

Comment: Have you seen [Dates causing line spread in `moderncv`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/253623/5764)?

Comment: That did not fix it @Werner

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend sticking the dates at the end of the location specification, separated by an `\hfill` to push it to the right margin:

[image]

```
\cventry{}{Research Assistant}{Research Group}{City, ST \hfill November 2022 -- Current}{}{
  % <cv entry content>
}
```

If you wish to keep your current format (with the date specified in the first argument, add the following to your preamble to update the way `\cventry` functions (necessarily pushing the first/date argument to the fourth, preceded by an `\hfill`):

```
\NewCommandCopy{\oldcventry}{\cventry}
\RenewDocumentCommand{\cventry}{ m m m m m }{\oldcventry{}{#2}{#3}{#4\hfill #1}{#5}}
```